# Automate IE with VBA - Click anchor button with span

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I am currently doing automation for uploading file in saleforce.

The HTML text is:

```
 <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onblur="chatter.getFeed().contentCommentActionBlur(this);" onfocus="chatter.getFeed().contentCommentActionFocus(this);" onclick="chatter.getFeed().createContentComment(this,'0D52700002cc67d', false, true);" onmousedown="chatter.getFeed().contentCommentActionMouseDown(this);" class="cxcontentcommentaction">
<img class="cxcontentcommentactionimg" src="/s.gif">
<span class="cxcontentcommentactiontext">Attach File</span>
</a>
</div>
```

For click the anchor user need to go down and press "Attach file" button.

I have tried with two different doing

1.Coding get element by anchor class="cxcontentcommentaction":

```
Set htmldoc = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentaction")
    htmldoc.Click
```

2.Coding get element by span class="cxcontentcommentactiontext":

```
Set htmldoc = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentactiontext")
    htmldoc.Click
```

For both I am getting error "Object doesn't support this property

After your comment, i have tried like this,

```
Set oElementCollection = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentactiontext")

    For Each link In oElementCollection
    If link.innerHTML = "Attach File" Then
        link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next link
```

I have tried for below HTML

```
<a href="javascript:window.invokeOnClickJS_00bG0000000ikPK%28this%29" class="menuButtonMenuLink">
Send an Email</a>
```

Below code is working properly for above html

```
Set oElementCollection = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("menuButtonMenuLink")


    For Each link In oElementCollection
    If link.innerHTML = "Send an Email" Then
        link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next link
```

But with "Attach File" button which mentioned in this question only getting problem.

Comment: It looks like this should be part of a form element - in which case just use `Forms(0).Submit` changing `0` to the correct index.

Answer (score 4):

The method `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements with this class name. This is because a `HTML` `DOM` can contain multiple elements with the same class name. That's why the plural form getElement`s`. So you need to know which element from the elements collection you need. If it is the first, then:

```
...
Set oElementCollection = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentaction")
oElementCollection(0).Click
...
```

If the first is not the right, then try

```
For i = 0 To oElementCollection.Length - 1
 MsgBox oElementCollection(i).innerHTML
Next
```

to find the right one.

**Edit:**

After your additions in the question:

with

```
Set oElementCollection = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentactiontext")
```

you are probably getting a collection of `span` objects not links.  But those `span` elements should be within links. So the links are their parents.

So

```
Set oElementCollection = mydoc.getElementsByClassName("cxcontentcommentactiontext")

    For Each span In oElementCollection
    If span.innerHTML = "Attach File" Then
        span.parentNode.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next span
```

Comment: For this class only one this anchor <a> available but when i execute your mentioned coding ,its executing another another file upload which not having mentioned class name.

Comment: Please inspect the `innerHTML` of all found elements to get the right one.

Comment: @Kathirvtv in addition to what Axel said above, consider also that each object you loop through (`oElementCollection(i)`) can be analyzed with the `.getAttribute('name of the attribute')` function that returns you the value of a certain attribute of the object. This might be useful to scan for example the `on-action` attributes calling the javascript that it's probably uploading your file and click the right one.

Comment: Attach screen not opening properly and also not navigate, i think its because of Attach file button available end of page so user need to do down manually and press the button.

Comment: @Kathirvtv if that button "Attach file" is in the page, it is also in the DOM of your HTML document. You can click it via VBA, though if it opens a frame I'm not sure you'll be able to navigate it through the same browser instance.

Comment: I have tried with InnerHTML and mentioned above, even-though Attach file button not executing properly.

Comment: @Kathir vtv: The `innerHTML` shall only help to find the right element number. It has nothing to do with the functionality.